# Генератор случайных чисел работает вне заданного диапазона

Tags: c

Пишу в Windows на DevC++. Генерация случайных чисел, работает всё корректно кроме диапазона 1000 - 1112, не могу понять причину. выдаёт значения в пределах от тысячи до 2200. В чём проблема подскажите?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

main()
{

  srand(time(NULL));

  for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) //1 to 2
  {
    printf("%d\n", 1 + rand() % 2);
  }

  for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)  //1 to 100
  {
    printf("%d\n", 1 + rand() % 100);
  }

  for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) //0 to 9
  {
    printf("%d\n", 0 + rand() % 9);
  }

  for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) //1000 to 1112
  {
    printf("%d\n", 1000 + rand() % 1112);
  }

  for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) //-1 to 1
  {
    printf("%d\n", -1 + rand() % 1);
  }

  for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) //-3 to 11
  {
    printf("%d\n", -3 + rand() % 11);
  }  
  system("PAUSE");
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если я всё правильно понял, то ошибка, по вашему мнению, здесь:

```
printf("%d\n", 1000 + rand() % 1112);
```

Эта строчка выведет случайное число от **1000** до **2111**(1000+1112-1). Возможно, это опечатка, если вы хотели получить диапазон 1000-1112. Можно заменить на `printf("%d\n", 1000 + rand() % 112);` и  всё работает.

Comment: Спасибо, работает, но я не могу понять почему оно изначально не работает ведь я указываю начало и конец диапазона, а именно от 1000 до 1112? Ведь по логике 1000 до 112 вообще должно выдавать ошибку? Можете разъяснить или написать где мне искать информацию по этому вопросу?

Comment: @steelhouse, 1000 *+* rand() % 1112 -- здесь *сумма*(а не начало и конец диапазона!) двух чисел **1000** и какого-то случайного от 0 до 1111(т.к. rand() % 1112 это случайное по модулю 1112). Поэтому и их сумма лежит в диапазоне от 1000 до 2111.

Comment: Просто неправильно понимал, в интернете приведены были примеры "начальное значение + rand() % конечное значение" и я с этого брал пример. Теперь буду немного лучше понимать.

Comment: @steelhouse, вы лучше разберитесь, что делает операция % и что возвращает rand.